# Sublime Text 2: run macro on multiple files

Tags: macros, sublimetext2, batch-processing

How can I run a macro I have built in Sublime Text 2, on multiple files without having to open each file individually?

Comment: Macros require a view to operate on, which means a file needs to be open. However, it should be fairly straightforward to build a plugin that accepts a list of file names as input, opens each one, runs the macro, then saves and closes the file.